# How to resolve cannot import name 'VisitableType' from 'sqlalchemy.sql.visitors'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Before three months ago I was able to deploy my first app on streamlit. It is a very simple app which takes some information from my students and send it to google spreadsheets. Yesterday I found that my app has an error message: cannot import name 'VisitableType' from 'sqlalchemy.sql.visitors'. I tried to run connect locally through jupyter notebook but I get the same massage.

```
cannot import name 'VisitableType' from 'sqlalchemy.sql.visitors'
```

It has been working perfect until now.
Here is my code:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import requests 
import sqlalchemy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import leafmap.foliumap as leafmap
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import text
import shillelagh

engine = create_engine(
    "shillelagh://",
     adapters=["gsheetsapi"],
     adapter_kwargs={
         "gsheetsapi": {
             "service_account_info": {
                 "type": "service_account",
                 "project_id": "###########",
                 "private_key_id": "############",
                 "private_key": "############",
                 "client_email": "#########################",
                 "client_id": "####################",
                 "auth_uri": "##############################",
                 "token_uri": "#########################",
                 "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
                 "client_x509_cert_url": "#######################"
            },
             "catalog":
             {
                 "interactive########": "#########################"
             }
         },
     },
)
```

Here is the error message:

```
File <string>:2, in create_engine(url, **kwargs)

File ~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\deprecations.py:277, in deprecated_params.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.warned(fn, *args, **kwargs)
    270     if m in kwargs:
    271         _warn_with_version(
    272             messages[m],
    273             versions[m],
    274             version_warnings[m],
    275             stacklevel=3,
    276         )
--> 277 return fn(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py:556, in create_engine(url, **kwargs)
    552 u = _url.make_url(url)
    554 u, plugins, kwargs = u._instantiate_plugins(kwargs)
--> 556 entrypoint = u._get_entrypoint()
    557 _is_async = kwargs.pop("_is_async", False)
    558 if _is_async:

File ~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\url.py:754, in URL._get_entrypoint(self)
    752 else:
    753     name = self.drivername.replace("+", ".")
--> 754 cls = registry.load(name)
    755 # check for legacy dialects that
    756 # would return a module with 'dialect' as the
    757 # actual class
    758 if (
    759     hasattr(cls, "dialect")
    760     and isinstance(cls.dialect, type)
    761     and issubclass(cls.dialect, Dialect)
    762 ):

File ~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py:363, in PluginLoader.load(self, name)
    361     if impl.name == name:
    362         self.impls[name] = impl.load
--> 363         return impl.load()
    365 raise exc.NoSuchModuleError(
    366     "Can't load plugin: %s:%s" % (self.group, name)
    367 )

File ~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\importlib_metadata\__init__.py:194, in EntryPoint.load(self)
    189 """Load the entry point from its definition. If only a module
    190 is indicated by the value, return that module. Otherwise,
    191 return the named object.
    192 """
    193 match = self.pattern.match(self.value)
--> 194 module = import_module(match.group('module'))
    195 attrs = filter(None, (match.group('attr') or '').split('.'))
    196 return functools.reduce(getattr, attrs, module)

File ~\Anaconda\lib\importlib\__init__.py:127, in import_module(name, package)
    125             break
    126         level += 1
--> 127 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1030, in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1007, in _find_and_load(name, import_)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:986, in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:680, in _load_unlocked(spec)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:850, in exec_module(self, module)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:228, in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

File ~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\shillelagh\backends\apsw\dialects\gsheets.py:19, in <module>
     16 from typing_extensions import TypedDict
     18 from shillelagh.adapters.api.gsheets.lib import get_credentials
---> 19 from shillelagh.backends.apsw.dialects.base import APSWDialect
     20 from shillelagh.exceptions import ProgrammingError
     22 _logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

File ~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\shillelagh\backends\apsw\dialects\base.py:10, in <module>
      8 from sqlalchemy.pool.base import _ConnectionFairy
      9 from sqlalchemy.sql.type_api import TypeEngine
---> 10 from sqlalchemy.sql.visitors import VisitableType
     11 from typing_extensions import TypedDict
     13 from shillelagh.adapters.base import Adapter

ImportError: cannot import name 'VisitableType' from 'sqlalchemy.sql.visitors' (C:\Users\############\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\visitors.py)

help(sqlalchemy.sql.visitors)
```

Could you please help me?

I tried to check visitors.py in the above mention directory. I even replace this file with one from sqlalchemy gitrepository. But it do not work.

Answer (score 1):

Shillelagh 1.2.0 or later is required to work with SQLAlchemy 2.0 (per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75278883/how-to-resolve-cannot-import-name-visitabletype-from-sqlalchemy-sql-visitors/75281358?noredirect=1#comment133187779_75281358) from [Beto Dealmeida](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807118/beto-dealmeida), the project maintainer).

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade shillelagh
```

If upgrading Shillelagh is not possible, try installing an earlier version of SQLAlchemy:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade 'sqlalchemy<2.0'
```

(`--upgrade` will also downgrade packages)

Comment: Thank you!!! Now it is working, but I have to check the same thing in streamlit cloud. I suppose I should do the same thing in requirements.txt file.

Comment: Ha, I'm the author of `shillelagh` and I found this thread trying to fix this problem. :)

Comment: Shillelagh 1.2.0 now supports SQLAlchemy 1.4 and 2.0.

Comment: @BetoDealmeida thanks for that. When you say now supports 1.4, did the previous version not work on 1,4 at all, or just not in "SQLA 2.0 mode"?

Comment: @snakecharmerb before it only worked in 1.4, now it works in 1.4 and 2.0.